# sending the email to the following server failed smtp.gmail.com 587 exception

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

I have gone through all questions which are on the same line as this, yet I have not found a solution. :S

I am using JavaMail to send mail and keep getting this exception. Below is the `StackTrace`

```
Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587

---- org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242)

---- org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267)

---- IMSPackage.MailServlet.postMail(MailServlet.java:2253)

---- sapphire.reports.AutoMailer.startTimer(AutoMailer.java:1027)

---- sapphire.reports.AutoMailer$1.call(AutoMailer.java:74)

---- java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)

---- java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)

---- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)

---- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
```

I have added these lines also -

```
xyz.setAuthentication(SMTPUsername, SMTPPassword);
xyz.setTLS(true);
```

I have checked my Username and password also, they're correct.
I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** what should be the `xyz.setSmtpPort()` set to? 25 or 587?

Comment: Is there any more information about the exception?  A more helpful message perhaps?  Maybe even a helpful error response from the SMTP server?

Comment: Is port 587 open on the firewall?

Comment: @David - This is all I got from the `StackTrace`. Is there anyother way I can get more information/message from?
@levelnis - I do not know how to check that. :/

Comment: Which OS is the server?

Comment: Open the windows firewall from Administrative Tools and add a new Outbound rule - Port 587 TCP. Set to Allow Connection

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).